# Send message to specific port on Windows cmd.exe

Tags: windows, sockets, ports

I'm playing with a program on desktop.  It's listening on port 5060.

However, I don't have anything sending to this location/host.

If I open my laptop's command line, is there a way to send a simple message to my desktop's ipaddress, on port 5060?

This is basically a simply chat program, for those asking what's going on.
I'm sure there's more to understand about ports and sockets.  So I'm positive there's some limitations to my simplicity.

Comment: This is TCP, right?  If UDP, that changes the answer a bit.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `telnet ipaddress port`.

Comment: telnet client can be installed from Windows Control Panel->Programs&Features->Turn Windows Features or of off->Telnet client

Comment: They stopped to install it by default? Curses!

Answer (score 2):

There is a netcat for windows (http://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows) Also I think ncat from the nmap project will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of testing, you probably want to locate and build the source code of a classic open source tool called netcat.